# Real polynomial involving vector product of complex conjugates

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be a complex vector and $\bar{v}$ be its complex conjugate, i.e. $v_i = \bar{\bar{v}}_i$. Let $x = (x_1, \dotsc,x_n)^T$ be a vector of variables. What is a simple argument to explain that $(v^T x) (\bar{v}^T x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients? Note that while $x$ may be complex the coefficients of the expanded polynomial are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{i,j} v_i \bar{v}_j x_i x_j = \sum_k |v_k|^2 x_k^2 + \sum_{i<j} (v_i \bar{v}_j + v_j \bar{v_i} )  x_i x_j$.

All the coefficients of $x_ix_j$ are real.

Comment: Nice. You made a typo though: it should be $v_i \bar{v}_j + v_j \bar{v}_i$.

Comment: Fixed! :-) ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is real, then $(\bar{v}^T x)$ is the complex conjugate of $(v^Tx)$. When you multiply something by its complex conjugate, the result must be real (and non-negative).

Comment: True but it also holds without making any assumption about $x$, i.e. the coefficients of the polynomial in $x$ are real after expansion of the polynomial. My question is why that is the case regardless of $x$ being real or complex.